# How can I use two parameters at once with xargs?

Tags: command-line, bash, xargs, command-line-arguments

I need to convert videos, but I don't know where are they, so I need to `find` them. How can I give the result and an output file name to [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) with [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs)?

I already found out that I can construct the two parameters with this command:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -printf "%p %f\n"
```

I can't find anything related in the `xargs` manual. I want something like this:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -printf "%p %f\n" | xargs ffmpeg -i {param1} -f flv {param2}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Those of you stumbling across this question because you're looking for an answer about multiple arguments with `xargs` _in general_ might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770432/xargs-with-multiple-arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick and preserve full path, handle space, rename `folder/movie.mov` to `folder/movie.flv`, etc.

```
find . -name "*.mov" | while read movie;do
  ffmpeg -i "$movie" -f flv "${movie%.mov}.flv"
done
```

And if I misunderstood you and you want all the .flv movies in the current directory, use this one instead:

```
find . -name "*.mov" | while read movie;do
  ffmpeg -i "$movie" -f flv "$(basename "${movie%.mov}.flv")"
done
```

Comment: If you want it as a oneliner, just put everything on one line. ;)

Answer (score 9):

The reason people use `xargs` in combination with find is that multiple file names will be passed to the same program invocation of whatever program `xargs` launches. For example, if `find` returns the files *foo*, *bar*, and *baz*, the following will run `mv` only once:

```
find sourceDir [...] -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t destDir
```

Effectively, it calls `mv` like the following:

```
mv -t destDir foo bar baz
```

If you don't need or want this behavior (as I assume is the case here), you can simply use `find`'s `-exec`.

---

In this case, an easy solution would be to write a short shell script, like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ -f "$1" ]] || { echo "$1 not found" ; exit 1 ; }
P="$1"
F="$( basename $P )"
ffmpeg -i "$P" -f flv "$F"
```

Save as `myffmpeg.sh` and run `chmod +x myffmpeg.sh`. Then, run the following:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -exec /path/to/myffmpeg.sh {} \;
```

This will invoke the shell script once for every file found. The shell script in turn extracts the file name from the full path, and calls `ffmpeg` with the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I did not get the solution I was expected, so I found out my own. 
@Daniel's answer is good, but it need a shell script. A one liner is quicker, and I like it better :) also simpler solution than writing a script.

I could use one argument and process it with `basename` and using `sh -c`

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -print0 | xargs -0 -i sh -c 'ffmpeg -i {} -f flv `basename {}`'
```

The -i tells to xargs to replace `{}` with the current argument. 
Command output inside `` printed out to standard output (bash feature) so `basename {}` will be evaluated as the bare file name and printed out. 
-0 for handling special file names properly, but you need to pass parameters with the -print0 option with find

Answer (score 4):

You have to do it like all the answers up there, but the EXACT use of xargs will be something like this:

```
echo argument1 argument2 argument3 | xargs -l bash -c 'echo this is first:$0 second:$1 third:$2' | xargs
```

So in your case it will be:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -printf "%p %f\n" | xargs -l bash -c 'echo ffmpeg -i $0 -f flv $1' | xargs
```

PS: This answers the question about xargs for those who is looking for an answer exactly for multiple `xargs` parameters in one `xargs` command.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can or how to do that with xargs.

But something like this should work for you:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -printf "%p %f\n" | while read -a HR ; do echo ffmpeg -i ${HR[0]} -f flv ${HR[1]} ;done
```

Comment: This doesn't properly handle spaces in file names/paths, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply move the options of the **ffmpeg** to fit the format of the results from the **find** command?

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -printf "%p %f\n" | xargs -r -n2 ffmpeg -f flv -i
```

Notice the addition of the **-r** option to **xargs** to prevent it from running **ffmpeg** if no **.mov** files are found.

I have added the **-n2** option to *xargs* to limit the number of items *xargs* processes to two at a time. In this case, the items are the file path and the file name. If no **-n** option is set, *xargs* will process as many input items as possible in a single execution.

Comment: This won't work once more than one file is found AFAICT.

Comment: This works only once for me too, but I dont understand why it stops after the first. Any idea ?

Comment: actually it doesnt work

Comment: Daniel-Beck and @Walkman were correct about the single execution. To solve that problem, I have edited this answer to limit the number of items xargs processes at a time via the **-n2** option. Without the **-n2**, *xargs* executes only once if it can handle the number of input items it receives through the pipe. It also should be pointed out that this solution only works when file names and file paths do not include whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Zoredache's answer using name binding (and using different separators to avoid the issue of spaces in file names):

```bsh
IFS="\t" find -iname "*.mov" -printf "%p\t%f\n" | while read path file; do
    ffmpeg -i $path -f flv $file
done
```

Of course you can also use the separators with the `find -a array` argument that the other answer had used, but sometimes named arguments are more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

You can run ffmpeg directly from the find command like this:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" -exec ffmpeg -i "%p" -f flv "%f" \;
```

Note the quotes around the parameters to ffmpeg, in case there are spaces in the filename, and the escaped semi-colon marks the end of the executed command.

Comment: Do you have documentation for the behaviour of -exec that also interprets printf formatting placeholders?

Comment: Nope.  Brain fart: I was thinking the %p and %f were find-things, not printf-things.  I've voted for your answer.